# Why is my public dictionary popping out 1004 errors?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to establish a public dictionary to query at various points in the use of my document. But- the document appears to "forget" about the dictionary assigned? Is there a problem with my code?

```
Dim hedDict As Scripting.Dictionary

Public Function headDict()
On Error Resume Next
Dim i As Long
Dim z As Long
Dim x As Variant
Dim c As Variant
Dim d As Variant
Set hedDict = New Dictionary
z = Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
Sheets("New Item Entry").Select
Range("A2").Select
i = 1
Do While i <= z
    c = Columns(i).Rows(1).Value
    d = i
    Call addToDict(hedDict, c, d)
    i = i + 1
Loop
End Function

Function addToDict(dic, iteem, val)
dic.Add iteem, val
End Function

Sub ChckTst()
Dim x as Long
x = Cells(i, hedDict("Order UOM Price")).Value
MsgBox (x)
End Sub
```

The subroutine above does various other things before calling on the dictionary, such as calling a plethora of variables, assigning an array, and creating a collection. If that could interfere, please let me know.

Thank you

Comment: Where do you call `headDict`?

Comment: I call it automatically when I close a userform. In testing, I've been manually running headDict for troubleshooting to receive the same errors.

Comment: I'm afraid you really haven't given us anything to go on. Half the relevant code is missing and I suspect from the error message that the content of the dictionary is not a valid column letter or number.

Comment: Dictionaries go by named keys, so the content is pulling the headers as the key and the column number as the content?

Comment: Is it impossible to have a second dictionary in my module? Thanks

Comment: You haven't posted the `addToDict` function. You can have as many Dictionaries declared as you like. Have you verified the content and data type of `hedDict("Order UOM Price")`?

Comment: Added the addToDict. Yes, I tested it with the MsgBox(x) in the headDict function. And the crazy thing- when I run headDict by itself, the msgBox shows with no problem, when I run it in the ChckTest subroutine it pops up with the error. Thank you

Comment: There is no `Msgbox` in `headDict`. What does `Msgbox TypeName(hedDict("Order UOM Price")) & ": " & hedDict("Order UOM Price")` return?

Comment: Yeah, that works in both queries. I was able to troubleshoot it down and I think I found out what the problem was. A singular capital letter difference in the key and the query. I appreciate all your help and I apologize that it was just some misc detail that was ravaging everything

Comment: No problem - at least it's fixed. :)